# OpenCSV reads only part of a file

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

I use openCSV to import files, but usually it reads only a part of a file. It deals with file containing ~5k rows but often 20k is problem for him (even CSV with 1 column).

When i tried to use BufferedReader instead of openCSV there wasnt problem with even 100k rows file but then i loose good openCSV parser.

Do you have any idea how to solve problem with openCSV or maybe you can recommend other good library for importing files in java?

Comment: OpenCSV can't handle such a large file because it is not streaming.  I recommend you looking into streaming this file.

Comment: Ok, as i sad i tried tu use BufferedReader but then i have to write parser on my own and usually its not enough to split file by separator, often its much more complicated. So are there any good libraries to import?

Comment: are you getting an exception , you might not see one if you are not printing the exception within your catch block.

Comment: nope, 100% there arent exceptions (i log everything and the part of file which is readed by csvReader is imported), just loop with reading next line ends reading only some part of the file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSVReader does not check the whole file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46404835/csvreader-does-not-check-the-whole-file)

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you have a bad csv file (ie you have a non escaped control character) and opencsv does not like that.

What I would suggest is that you look at the line after the last line processed and for giggles remove it and see if you get more processed after that.  If so it is not a size matter and you now know which line is causing an issue.

As a disclaimer I am the maintainer of the opencsv project and I have performance tested opencsv with over a million records (CSVReader and CSVWriter) without issue - as long as you do the one by one methods.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to do with the file? Have tried reading line by line ?

```
    CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("yourfile.csv"));
    String [] nextLine;
    while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
        // do whatever you want here
    }
```

Comment: i do it exactly the same, but CSVReader reads only hundreds to several thousend first lines and cant see rest of the file, eg. reads 300 rows (in 1k rows file) and loop ends without errors (there arent additional conditions to break the loop)

Comment: small correction: in constructor i use InputStreamReader, but i tried also BufferedReader and FileReader too.

Comment: I have the same issue. Most days it reads the whole daily file we get, but once a month there is a file (that is perfectly fine) it stops in the middle for no reason, no special character, no hidden characters. We even looked in a hex editor. If we remove the line it goes beyond. We even get different lines to with readNext versus readAll; 344, 190 lines respectively in a file with 649 lines. Using Groovy's files.splitEachLine gets all 649 lines. But we don't use Groovy in our app. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I just had an issue with OpenCSV 3.4. It could read only as much data as the BufferedReader's buffer size. It didn't matter whether my own BufferdReader was used or internal one.

I have resolved it by using OpenCSV 3.10. No problem there.