# CSVReader does not check the whole file

Tags: java, csv

I am trying to open a csv file using openCSV, iterate over every column and if the userID is different write a new JavaBean pair at the end of the file.

The problem is that the reader only checks the first column of my file and not the whole file. While created, the file contains only a header and nothing else. The program will check every column and if the sudoID is different it will write it to the file. If the sudoID in the first line is equal to the the one imported from my main class it will recognise it and not write it. But if this -same- sudoID is in the second row it will not recognise it and will write it again.

For instance, if my CSV looks like this it will work:

```
"Patient_id Pseudo_ID",
"32415","PAT106663926"
```

If it looks like this it will re-write the sudoID:

```
"Patient_id Pseudo_ID",
"32416","PAT104958880"
"32415","PAT106663926"
```

Thanks!
My Code:

```
public class CSVConnection {

@SuppressWarnings({ "deprecation", "resource", "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
public String getID(String sID,String pseudoID) throws IOException, CsvDataTypeMismatchException, CsvRequiredFieldEmptyException{
    try {
     CsvToBean csv = new CsvToBean();
     String csvFilename = "CsvFile.csv";
     Writer writer= new FileWriter(csvFilename,true);
     CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvFilename),',','"',1);

      ColumnPositionMappingStrategy strategy = new ColumnPositionMappingStrategy();
      strategy.setType(PatientCSV.class);
      String[] columns = new String[] {"patID","pseudoID"};
      strategy.setColumnMapping(columns);
     //Set column mapping strategy
      StatefulBeanToCsv<PatientCSV> bc = new StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder<PatientCSV>(writer).withMappingStrategy(strategy).build();
      List patList = csv.parse(strategy, csvReader);

      for (Object patObj : patList) {

          PatientCSV pat = (PatientCSV) patObj;
          if(((PatientCSV) patObj).getPatID().equals(sID)){

              return pat.getPseudoID();
          }
          else
          {  

              PatientCSV pat1 = new PatientCSV();
              pat1.setPatID(sID);
              pat1.setPseudoID(pseudoID);
              patList.add(pat1);
              /*Find a way to import it to the CSV*/
              bc.write(pat1);
              writer.close();
              return pseudoID;
          }
      }


} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();

}
    return null;


}




public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException, CsvDataTypeMismatchException, CsvRequiredFieldEmptyException{
    CSVConnection obj = new CSVConnection();
    String sID="32415";
    String pseudoID="PAT101830150";
    obj.getID(sID,pseudoID);
}
```

}

and the Java Bean :

```
public class PatientCSV {
private String patID;
private String pseudoID;


public String getPatID() {
    return patID;
}


public void setPatID(String patID) {
    this.patID = patID;
}


public String getPseudoID() {
    return pseudoID;
}


public void setPseudoID(String pseudoID) {
    this.pseudoID = pseudoID;
}


public PatientCSV(String patID, String pseudoID) {
    super();
    this.patID = patID;
    this.pseudoID = pseudoID;
}


public PatientCSV() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}


public String toString()
   {
      return "Patient [id=" + patID + ", pseudoID=" + pseudoID +  "]";
   }
```

}

Comment: Please don't just suppress all those warnings. They're there for a *good* reason, i.e. you should address and fix them.

Comment: @QBrute Good point. I intended to change this after I find a solution to my problem. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets inspect your `for loop`

```
for (Object patObj : patList) {

      PatientCSV pat = (PatientCSV) patObj;
      if(((PatientCSV) patObj).getPatID().equals(sID)){

          return pat.getPseudoID();
      }
      else
      {  

          PatientCSV pat1 = new PatientCSV();
          pat1.setPatID(sID);
          pat1.setPseudoID(pseudoID);
          patList.add(pat1);
          /*Find a way to import it to the CSV*/
          bc.write(pat1);
          writer.close();
          return pseudoID;
      }
  }
```

So in the case you mention it is not working as expected, meaning that the line that matches your input is the second line:

```
"Patient_id Pseudo_ID",
"32416","PAT104958880"
"32415","PAT106663926"
```

So you call: `getID("32415", "PAT106663926")`
What happens in your loop is:

1. You take the first element of your `csv` patients, the one with `id`: `32416`,
2. check if it matches with the `id` given as input to your method, `32415`.
3. It does not match so it goes to the `else` part. There it creates the new patient (with the same `patID` and `pseudoID` as the 2nd row of your csv) and stores it in the file.
4. So by now you should have 2 entries in your csv with the same data  `"32415","PAT106663926"`.

I think that this is the error, in your `for loop` you should check against **all** entries if there is a match, and then create the patient and store it to the csv.

An example:

```
PatientCSV foundPatient = null;
for (Object patObj : patList) {

  PatientCSV pat = (PatientCSV) patObj;
  if(((PatientCSV) patObj).getPatID().equals(sID)){
      foundPatient = pat;
  }
}

if (foundPatient == null) {
    foundPatient = new PatientCSV();
    foundPatient.setPatID(sID);
    foundPatient.setPseudoID(pseudoID);
    patList.add(foundPatient);
    /*Find a way to import it to the CSV*/
    bc.write(foundPatient);
    writer.close();
}

return foundPatient.getPseudoID();
```

P.S. The above example is written very quickly, just to give you the idea what needs to be done.

Comment: Thank you very much. That's exactly what I was thinking it will be the problem . Great response and very analytic as well.

Comment: Tested and work awesome. I tried to do a for(int i =0 ;i< patList.size();i++) and then keep a flag and the place where I find the ID but I will go with your solution. Thanks again.